# ggplot across multiple categories

Tags: r, ggplot2

for the below data, can we plot ggplot across categories as shown below. Basically y axis is the count of customers across Months

```
df
Date    App Customers
Jan-01  A   Cust1
Feb-01  B   Cust2
Mar-01  A   Cust1
Apr-01  B   Cust2
May-01  C   Cust1
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can `count` number of rows for each Month and `App` and plot the data.

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

df %>%
  count(Date, App) %>%
  mutate(Date = as.Date(paste0(Date, '-01'), '%b-%y-%d')) %>%
  ggplot(aes(Date, n, color = App)) + 
  geom_line() + 
  scale_x_date(date_labels = '%b %Y')
```